# Trouble Getting Chrome Through Selenium Hub

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver, 2.25  I have a local hub set up with this json setting for chrome and firefox:

```
[
    {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "maxInstances": 5,
        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "maxInstances": 5,
        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
],
```

I can start a webdriver firefox session like this:

```
capability = getattr(webdriver.DesiredCapabilities, "FIREFOX")
dd=webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', capability)
```

which works fine
but if I try to start a Chrome session like this:

```
capability = getattr(webdriver.DesiredCapabilities, "CHROME")
dd=webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', capability)
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 62, in **init**
>       self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 104, in start_session
>       'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 155, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 147, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: None ; Stacktrace: Method innerGet threw an error in None

But I can start a direct connection to Chrome like this:

```
dd=webdriver.Chrome()
```

Without any problem.

What can I do to get to Chrome through my Selenium Hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the chrome driver, info about that [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

**UPDATE**

---

Based on a [sample json setup file](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNode.json)
and steps provided in the first link, seems like the browser name should not be in Upper but in fact lower case.

So change `CHROME` to `chrome`

Example

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://localhost:9515", DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

and in your case, I would assume

```
dd=webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities.chrome())
```

Comment: Isn't the same chrome driver required for webdriver.Chrome()?

Comment: Yes, it appears that it is.  If I rename the chromedriver executable, the local webdriver.Chrome() ceases to work. Put it back and it works again.  Seems that I have chromedriver set up.

Comment: Yes, as I said on the first line.  2.25

Comment: oops Sorry, my last try `capability = getattr(webdriver.DesiredCapabilities, "chrome")
dd=webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', capability)`, change the `CHROME` to `chrome`

Comment: Thanks, but DesiredCapabilities only has "CHROME", not "chrome" or "Chrome".  Appreciate your trying.

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't help either.  The hub wants the node to use "chrome", but the webdriver.DesiredCapabilities object only wants "CHROME"

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer... it's totally incorrect.  The property on the `DesiredCapabilities` class is named `CHROME` (all caps), not `chrome`.  Also, It is a dictionary, not a method.  Check the source.

Answer (score 2):

I had EXACTLY the same problem.

The thing is, unlike Firefox, Chrome needs separate chromdriver.exe to act as bridge between browser and driver.

From the documentation:

> The ChromeDriver consists of three separate pieces. There is the
>   browser itself ("chrome"), the language bindings provided by the
>   Selenium project ("the driver") and an executable downloaded from the
>   Chromium project which acts as a bridge between "chrome" and the
>   "driver". This executable is called "chromedriver", but we'll try and
>   refer to it as the "server" in this page to reduce confusion.

[Download chromdriver.exe here](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list)

And put it in your chrome binary dir.

I then use a .bat file to launch my hub with this listing:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe" -jar D:\soft\selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar
```

I then execute the following Python code on my Linux box, it worked flawlessly once I put chromedriver.exe in the Chrome dir and launched the hub with correct path parameters:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "http://192.168.1.115:4444/wd/hub"
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor = url, desired_capabilities = {'browserName':'chrome'})
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Hope this helps you and the others with the same problem. Finding the solution was of course not to take firefox approach for granted and RTFM:
[Chrome driver documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)